# Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index, when I'm trying to set values to Procedure

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

I have a procedure like below,

```
   create or replace procedure insertemployee3(
   p_eno employee2.eno%type,
   p_ename employee2.ename%type,
   p_eadd employee2.eadd%type,
   p_ecmpy employee2.ecmpy%type)
   is
   begin
   insert into employee2 (eno,ename, eadd, ecmpy)
   values (111,p_ename,'HYD',p_ecmpy);
  commit;
 end;
```

And when I'm trying to set values for `p_ename, p_ecmpy` through `PrepareStatement` object I'm getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index.
```

Here is my Java Code:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
        "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","manager");            
    CallableStatement stmt=con.prepareCall("{call insertemployee3(?,?)}");              
        stmt.setString(2,"Amit");           
        stmt.setString(4,"Accenture");          
        stmt.execute();               
        System.out.println("success");
```

In the above code I'm trying to set values for `p_ename, p_ecmpy`.

Please help me to get rid of this exception.

Comment: The column indexes of your two parameters are 1 and 2, not 2 and 4. But your called statement has four parameters, not two. Not much here that makes sense.

Comment: Your stored procedure is expecting four (4) arguments so you need to provide all four, even if the SP code only actually uses two of them. Just pass it junk values (e.g., `0` or `""`) for parameters 1 and 3.